# Synchronized vector- java server

Tags: multithreading, jsp, vector, synchronization

So I am building a website according to MVC Pattern. I use Eclipse/Tomcat.

I have a PostAccess class, which retrieves my posts from the DB, it creates an vector with PostBean items in it. The servlet gives the vector to the jsp file and the jsp file creates the html etc.

My problem is that more than one thread is interacting with the vector, so I get this on eclipse:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Vector$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
```

As i learned from googling, this error comes because of not having synchronized the threads that edit the vector.

But where exactly should i do the synchronization?

This code is in my PostAccess class :

```
public synchronized Vector<Post> RetrievePosts() throws SQLException
{
```

Vector c = (Vector)(new Vector());return c;
}

This is in my Servlet class:

```
public synchronized  void process(ServletContext servletContext,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    Vector<Post> c = (Vector<Post>)(new Vector<Post>());

    try {
        PostDAO pDAO=new PostDAO(servletContext);

        c=(Vector<Post>) pDAO.RetrievePosts();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    request.setAttribute("posts", c);
}
```

This is in my jsp:

```
<% Vector<Post> c =(Vector<Post>)request.getAttribute("posts");

Iterator<Post> i = c.iterator();  
herePost p=(Post)i.next();


                        while (!c.isEmpty()) { %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think two threads are working on the same Vector as in the code you show the Vector is declared within the process method (I'm assuming that that's the one that gets called by doGet) and thus it's private to the thread that's handling the request.  So, unless something really funky is going on in PostAccess I think you can rule out threads thrashing the Vector.

However, this looks like it could be the cause of the problem:

```
Iterator<Post> i = c.iterator();  
herePost p=(Post)i.next();
```

If the vector is empty to start with that will cause a java.util.NoSuchElementException as the isEmpty() test is done afterwards.

Comment: ok you were right, i removed the iterator and i used just a counter and problem solved! thanx!